# how to get plugin url in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I am new in wordpress, doing a plug in for word press site. Here is a problem with me, i want to get plug in url with my plug in name dynamically.That is url like "sitename/wp-content/plugins/plug in name".Here plugin name should be dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get plugin base name  `plugin_basename(__FILE__)`

refer here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_basename